# What's the auto-layout way of establishing the width of buttons with only images in them?

Tags: macos, cocoa, layout, autolayout, nsbutton

I have three textured buttons that only have images in them:

[image]

and I'm using auto-layout to establish the distances amongst them and between them and the borders. Since I didn't do anything to establish the width of the buttons, at runtime, they appear like this:

[image]

I could just set a fixed width in pixels but in my experience, fixed widths in UI is generally asking for trouble. What is the proper auto-layout way of letting have a nice width?

Comment: I think a fixed width is fine in this case. Why do you think it would be problematic for this specific user interface?

Comment: @StefanArentz I find fixed amounts in pixels in UI inherently problematic. I'm used to build UIs with Gtk/Qt where everything is elastic/vector-based. One problem that I could think is that I'm not sure how a fixed pixel width would interface with retina screens. Another problem is that I'm not sure how wide those images will be in the future, they used to be wider in previous versions of Mac OS X if I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In auto layout, you are supposed to use points as a unit instead of pixels ([you can find more details here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW15)). So don't worry about Retina thing that match.

And regarding to second point, how about setting a width as you preferred but a relatively lower priority (meaning *not* Required). So that if the images get wider/narrower in the future and that causes a problem, it allows to lay out views based on its intrinsic size, not those fixed values.

Thanks.